# If i am trying to create a diray app using django, how can i get it show show me different diary entries based on the current logged in user?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-class-based-views

im currently in the process of building a diary app in django. I have created multiple users (e.g User A and User B). However, when user A logs in, user A can see User B's entries.

How can i lock it down, so only User B can see User B's entries and when User A logs in, User A can have a personal entry view? (do i need to create a different view?)

views.py for my diary app:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView,
)
from .models import Entry
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect




# Create your views here.
class ELV(ListView):
    model = Entry
    queryset = Entry.objects.all().order_by("-date_created") #takes all the entries and orders it by date
    template_name = 'entries\entry_list.html'

    
class EDV(DetailView):
    model = Entry
    template_name = 'entries\entry_detail.html'
    
    

class ECV(CreateView):
    model = Entry
    fields = ["title", "content"]
    success_url = reverse_lazy("entry-list")
    template_name = 'entries\entry_form.html'
    

class EUV(UpdateView):
    model = Entry
    fields = ["title", "content"]
    template_name = 'entries\entry_update_form.html'
    
    def get_success_url(self):   
         
        return reverse_lazy(
            "entry-detail",
            kwargs={"pk": self.object.pk}
        )
        

class EntryDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Entry
    success_url = reverse_lazy("entry-list")
    template_name = 'entries\entry_delete.html'
```

Does it have anything to do with user sessions? - i'm not sure, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this easily. But before this you have to add an extra field in your `Entry` model.

```py
# models.py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='entries', default=None)
    # your other remaining fields
```

and make sure to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands after adding the new field. And in your `views.py` file, add a `get_queryset(self)`

```py
# Create your views here.
class ELV(ListView):
    model = Entry
    template_name = 'entries\entry_list.html'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Entry.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by("-date_created")
```

PS: And it's a good idea to add a `LoginRequiredMixin` to make sure only the `authenticated` got the access you `ListView`

```py
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class ELV(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
   # ...
```

Here is [docs link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin)

Comment: @musbashar thanks you so much!, i am currently trying this but i seem to get this error message when running 'python manage.py makemigrations'...... (It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'user' to entry without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.). Any ideas on what i can do here?

Comment: You can add the `default=None` to the `ForeignKey`. By the way, I have updated the answer too.

Comment: Have a look at the model fields in answer.

Comment: thank you!! - will give this a try, just trying to debug an error when i try to migrate the files

Comment: Back, thank you very mcuh @Mubashar !! - it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to add this bit to my entry create view (ECV), once done, worked like a charm!

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    return super(ECV, self).form_valid(form)
```